# Updating necessary data using just one function

Tags: php, object-oriented, security, mysqli

My objective is to update necessary data using one function instead of having different functions to update different fields. So, I've created one and I think this is not really elegant, efficient or secure. I would seriously like a review if possible.

> ```
> Key.
>
>     $data is an array.
>     $data[0] = column to update.
>     $data[1] = new data.
>     $data[2] = username of the user.
> ```

Code:

```php
public function handleUserDataUpdate($data) {
    if($userMapper->validate($data) === true) {
        $userMapper->update($data);
    } else {
        $errors['count'] = count($errors);
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

---

`UserMapper` Class Methods:

```php
public function validate($data) {
    switch ($data[0]) {
        case 'rank':
            if(empty($data[1])) {
                $errors[] = "The rank field cannot be empty!";
            }
            if(count($errors) > 0) {
                return $errors;
            } else { 
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case 'display_name':
            if(empty($data[1]) || strlen($data[1]) < 3 || strlen($data[1] > 20)) {
                $errors[] = "The display name should contain at least 3 to 20 characters";
            }
            if(count($errors) > 0) {
                return $errors;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }
}
public function update($data) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET " . $data[0] . "=? WHERE username=?";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($this->sql);
    $query->bind_param('ss', $data[1], $data[2]);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
}
```

Comment: i would use ? for data[0] too

Comment: @MarcoAcierno what do you mean?

Comment: Here `$sql = "UPDATE users SET " . $data[0] . "=? WHERE username=?";` instead of write `" . $data[0] . "` you could use `?`.

Comment: I agree Marco, this should work
`$sql = "UPDATE users SET ?=? WHERE username=?";
$query->bind_param('sss', $data[0], $data[1], $data[2]);`

Comment: You use an if-statement to check for errors, then use a second to check if errors have been set. You could compress this to one if/else-statement checking for errors and immediatly returning either the error or (else) returning true.

Comment: Actually, you could still use the first if (checking for errors and saving them into an array/object/variable) and move the counting if-statement after the switch. This way you only need 1 check instead of copying it to each case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Why `update` is a public function? I suppose it's inside a class, so it should be private. If you make it public all checks you do inside `handleUserDataUpdate` and `validate` are useless since someone could just use `update($data)` and put malicious data inside it. The same should be for `validate`, seems like the only function which should be public is `handleUserDataUpdate`. And you can be sure, as user of your API i'm more invited to use `update` than `handleUserDataUpdate`.
2. The name `handleUserDataUpdate` is a bit strange for a public function, i mean `handleUserDataUpdate` it could be OK for a private method since you can change it every time you want and you free to do what you want. But when it's a public method choose your names careful! `updateUserData($data)`? Or simply, if the class name is `UserDataEditor` you can use `apply` or `commit()` (If you know `Android` it could be something like `SharedPreferences`)
3. An array? Really, no! Why not a class? I mean, with an array you should remember:

   1. Index 0 is X
   2. Index 1 is Y
   3. Index 2 is Z

   No! Really, after a bit of time you will need to read the source to remember what was 0, 1 and 2.

   You can use a custom class like:

   ```
   class UpdateField {
      private $fieldName;
      private $newValue;
      private $userName;
   }
   ```

   I have the feeling like it could be a great system if:

   1. `UpdateField` was an interface, which `RankUpdate`, `DisplayNameUpdate` implement so inside the class you have the logic of the validate and the `ValidatorSystem` just execute the method `UpdateField->update()` which returns an array of errors or true in case of success.
   2. With this you could reuse `UpdateField` to update **everything** not just a userfield.

   but instead of use an array, you can improve it:

   1. You can check if `fieldName` is valid in the constructor of `UpdateField` and throw an exception if it's not a valid field.
   2. The method `validate` could be inside this class too, no?
4. This block of code

   ```
   if(count($errors > 0)) {
           return $errors;
   } else {
           return true;
   }
   ```

   ignoring the fact that i hate when a function first return an array or a boolean (i know, it's in the default PHP functions BUT IT'S STUPID! It let me feel like: You will never know what this function will return!) It could be improved in one line with:

   ```
   return count($errors) > 0 ? $errors : true;
   ```

   but wait, is `if(count($errors > 0))` correct? It count the value of a boolean? It's what you want?
5. @Vogel612 already said about problems inside `update` functions.

About point 3, take for the moment only the fact that you **should** use a class instead of an array, about the system i'm thinking it's just an idea in my mind maybe it cannot be done in PHP.

Comment: Love you marco! I want to understand interfaces. Why are they used? If you teach me that I will love you forever!!!

Comment: Fixed, anyway maybe an interface could not be appropriate here... maybe an abstract class to reduce some duplicate code. If you want to learn interfaces i think it's better to you to read interface page of php. It's nothing of special.

Comment: wtf, its a  mistake. I'll fix my main code.

Answer (score 7):

[You are vulnerable to SQL Injections.](http://www.bobby-tables.com) Even when you are using Prepared statements, doing It wrong will kill you.

> ```
> $sql = "UPDATE users SET " . $data[0] . "=? WHERE username=?";
> ```

This makes you exposed to SQL injections because your function is not private. You should not allow "user" access to "critical" functions. make that function private and you should be good to go.

As soon as the user is allowed to set `$data[0]` you're screwed.

Comment: I stated it to you personally that the user is not allowed to set it

Comment: Not allowed how? By telling them to pretty please not use a public API?

Comment: That's not how it works, public vs private has nothing to do with the SQL injection he has.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha in fact it does. If you can **ensure** that there is no SQL-Critical stuff in `$data[0]` it should be fine. But as the function is public, you can't ensure that and are thus vulnerable to sql injection